# uitextfield positionFromPosition:offset not working emojis

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, emoji

I am trying to implement my own keyboard containing emojis. 
For this purpose I am inserting the emoji in the cursor position.

This works fine if no 4-bytes emoji characters exist in UITextField. Otherwise the app gets crashed.

I am posting the insertion code here. Can someone point out how to solve the issue?

```
UITextField *field = self.textField;
UITextRange *range = field.selectedTextRange;
int pos = [field offsetFromPosition:field.beginningOfDocument toPosition:range.end];
NSString * firstHalfString = [field.text substringToIndex:pos];  
NSString * secondHalfString = [field.text substringFromIndex:pos];  
field.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@%@", firstHalfString, emoticon, secondHalfString];
UITextPosition *newPos = [field positionFromPosition:field.beginningOfDocument offset:pos + 1];
field.selectedTextRange = [field textRangeFromPosition:newPos toPosition:newPos];
```

this line returns nil if there are emojis in the text:

```
UITextPosition *newPos = [field positionFromPosition:field.beginningOfDocument offset:pos + 1];
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is such a niche problem, but it was annoying the hell out of me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end I solved this by writing my own length and offset calculation methods which count 4-byte characters as 1 character, not two.

```
@implementation NSString (UnicodeAdditions)
-(NSInteger)utf32length {
    const char* bytes = [self UTF8String];
    int length = [self lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
    int newLength = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        if (((unsigned char)bytes[i] >> 7) == 0b00000000)  {
          newLength++;
        }
        else if (((unsigned char)bytes[i] >> 5) == 0b00000110) {
            newLength++;
            i+=1;
        }
        else if (((unsigned char)bytes[i] >> 4) == 0b00001110) {
            newLength++;
            i+=2;
        }
        else if (((unsigned char)bytes[i] >> 3) == 0b00011110) {
            newLength++;
            i+=3;
        }
    }
    return newLength;
}


-(NSInteger)utf32offsetWithOffset:(NSInteger)offset {
    const char* bytes = [self UTF8String];
    int length = [self lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
    int newLength = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<length && offset!=0; i++) {
        if (((unsigned char)bytes[i] >> 7) == 0b00000000)  {
            offset--;
            newLength++;
        }
        else if (((unsigned char)bytes[i] >> 5) == 0b00000110) {
            offset--;
            newLength++;
            i+=1;
        }
        else if (((unsigned char)bytes[i] >> 4) == 0b00001110) {
            offset--;
            newLength++;
            i+=2;
        }
        else if (((unsigned char)bytes[i] >> 3) == 0b00011110) {
            offset-=2;
            newLength++;
            i+=3;
        }
    }
    return newLength;
}

@end
```

see the full blog post http://bit.ly/PT9VSz

Answer (score 2):

I found another way, it works for me:

```
- (NSRange)findRealRangeForString:(NSString *)text range:(NSRange)range
{
    __block int loc = 0;
    __block int len = 0;
    [text enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, text.length) options:(NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences) usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop)
     {
         if (substringRange.location < range.location)
             loc++;
         else if (substringRange.location < range.location + range.length)
             len++;
         else
             *stop = YES; 
     }];
    return NSMakeRange(loc, len);
}
```

Comment: Note that text is the full text, and that range is the range of the text you want to find the true range of.

Comment: @AlexBeals sure. Looks like my function name is not very clear. Thanks for description. Function tries to correct given range of string not to divide multi-character symbols.